# Search by ID but display row information within a drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a database full of names. (First_name, last_name, etc...)

Each person has an ID.

I want my drop down menu to display full names (joining first_name and last_name together, and omitting the id)

Right now I can display either their Id, their first_name, or last_name. But not a combination of any of these.

```
<p>Reported By:
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db ("widget_corp");

$sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM people GROUP BY id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='id'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['id'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is this -

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . "</option>";
}
```

And you do not need a `GROUP BY` clause on your query if each person's id is unique.